# passing an argument from an aspx page to a UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

I am having a problem passing a variable to a user control.
When I pass a hard-coded value, my control works fine. However passing a variable is not working.

My ASPX code:

```
<% System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Operate Flag is set to: " + operateFlag); %>
<uc:menu ID="navigationMenu" runat="server" operate="<%# operateFlag %>" />
```

From debug output, it is clear that operateFlag is set to 'true'.

My control codebehind only has synthesized methods as below:

```
public partial class MenuControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public bool operate { get; set; }
}
```

I also print out the received value from inside the control:

```
<% System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Operate Flag is received as: \'" + operate + "\'"); %>
```

Here, operate is received by the control as False.

Comment: Please read: [Communication between the page and a `UserControl`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8797/Mastering-Page-UserControl-Communication).

Comment: I am setting the value of `operate` inside `OnLoad()` method of ASPX page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to get my page working. Still do not understand what was wrong with the original "form."
Now, as before from OnLoad(), I set the property of the control instead of passing a variable as:

```
navigationMenu.operate = false;
```

It solves my need.